# Concatenate column from many bed files into single bed file

Tags: bash, bed

I have n bed files in the format:

n.bed

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 10000 | 4 | 331 |
| chr1 | 10000 | 20000 | 6 | 154 |
| chr1 | 20000 | 30000 | 3 | 12 |

I would like to take column 4 (4, 6, 3) from each bed file and output as a single table file (csv/tsv/exact format doesn't matter), where columns 4 through 4+n are labelled the name of each bed file and contain column 4.

For example, take two bed files:

1.bed :

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 10000 | 4 | 331 |
| chr1 | 10000 | 20000 | 6 | 154 |
| chr1 | 20000 | 30000 | 3 | 12 |

2.bed :

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 10000 | 2 | 412 |
| chr1 | 10000 | 20000 | 7 | 14 |
| chr1 | 20000 | 30000 | 2 | 155 |

I would like the output to be:

| chrom | start | end | 1.bed | 2.bed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 0 | 10000 | 4 | 2 |
| chr1 | 10000 | 20000 | 6 | 7 |
| chr1 | 20000 | 30000 | 3 | 2 |

My current attempt has been to use bedops:

```bash
$ bedops --everything *.bed \
    | bedmap --echo-map - \
    | awk '(split($0, a, ";") == 3)' - \
    | sed 's/\;/\n/g' - \
    | sort-bed - \
    | uniq - \
    > answer.bed
```

However this produces the output:

```
Error: Unable to find file: 1.bed
```

Comment: please update the question with *a)* details on how you match/join rows from different files (match on chrom+start+end? what if start/end do not match and/or overlap?) and *b)* the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: In your example, the bed files don't have a header section. Is this guaranteed? If not, how should the header of the common file be constructed? If you don't have bed headers, you could use awk and, while processing one of the file, store the relevant data into an array, and then when procssing the second file, print to stdout the combined data.

Comment: What is your attempt? Are [this](http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/bed.html) a real bed file sample? Is bash required? Check these csv manipulation samples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361927/merge-two-csv-files-into-one-and-keep-just-one-header-in-bash/74362761#74362761  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935210/extract-output-values-from-disk-image-file-as-strings-in-linux/76935417#76935417

Comment: @user1934428 This is guaranteed, none of the bed files have a header. I will test using awk.

I have updated the post with my attempt. These are correct bed samples, the chrom, start, end are the only required columns, and there can be any number of further tab separated columns (two in my example) that in my case capture mutation information data. The example that you linked is correct, but the optional columns are often switched out for variant data.

Comment: @JRichardsz : Though a headerless bed-file **may** be a valid csv file, bed-files in general are not necessarily valid csv. I don't quite see, how csv manipulation tools would help here.

Comment: @markp-fuso I would like to match on chrom and start. However, in every one of my bed files, the chrom, start, and end columns are identical, so I am hoping that I won't have to do any joins and can instead just concatenate.

Comment: The *nix `join` command should be able to do this for you. `man join`, and [here is a good/simple QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836480/620097). Good luck.

Comment: how many filenames does `*.bed` expand to? try running in smaller batches. cf. https://github.com/bedops/bedops/issues/249

Comment: please update the question to explicitly state the delimiter in  your sample files ... tab? fixed width? something else? in your `awk` code it appears you're looking for a semicolon (`;`) delimiter but there are no semicolons in the sample data ... so at this point what's been presented is a bit confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- none of the input files have a header record
- all input files have the same number of rows where ...
- the first 3 columns are `chrom`, `start` and `end` and ...
- there's at least one additional (4th) column
- all input/ouput field delimiters are tabs
- rows (from different input files) are joined based on the triple key of `chrom` + `start` + `end`
- all input files have the same set of keys (ie, we don't have to worry about a key missing from some input files)
- the input files are already sorted by key

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="\t"
         hdr = "chrom" OFS "start" OFS "end"
       }
FNR==1 { hdr = hdr OFS FILENAME }
       { key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3
         lines[FNR] = (FNR==NR ? key : lines[FNR]) OFS $4
       }
END    { print hdr
         for (i=1;i<=FNR;i++)
             print lines[i]
       }
' *.bed
```

**NOTES:**

- this single `awk` script replaces OP's current `bedops | bedmap | awk | sed | sort-bed | uniq` code
- this *assumes* the `*.bed` files already exist and are not the output from `bedops | bedmap`

This generates:

```
chrom   start   end     1.bed   2.bed
chr1    0       10000   4       2
chr1    10000   20000   6       7
chr1    20000   30000   3       2
```